# Dialog close buttons will not work if page loaded into dialog contains references to jQuery also

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a dynamic dialog being created that loads a page. The close buttons do not work on it.
Here is the example of the buttons not working: http://www.tanela.com/testbin/dialogtest1.html

I know what the problem is, I just do not know the solution.

The page that is being loaded also contains references to jQuery, If I remove these references then every thing works fine.
Here is the example of the buttons working: http://www.tanela.com/testbin/dialogtest2.html

On the page being loaded, sometimes I have functions that do need jquery, thus my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `$.load()` wrong: you shouldn't load a full web page (with `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>`) with it, only the piece of HTML that you need. Strip dialogtest1a.html down to just the content you want to place inside the dialog.

If for some reason you have to have a full web page inside the dialog, use an iframe to contain the second document.

Comment: I will think on it. I used to use iframes, but the dialogs seemed to load real slow.
So, id in my dialog I display, lets say a table with records, and the user clicks delete-record, can I used a confirm-dialog? how would that work? Would it close the main dialog before displaying the confirm-dialog?

Comment: GREAT, just did some testing, Thanks
In case any others are curious http://www.tanela.com/testbin/dialogtest3.html